# Changing Parallel.ForEach to better approach

Tags: c#, performance, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I use Task Parallel Library(TPL) and C# 4.5 to implement this business logic in a Windows Service Application:

- Get JSON result (a list) from remote RESTful API
- For each item, retrieve JSON result of details from another remote
  RESTful API
- For each item's attached business objects(1000+), use
  Parallel.ForEach saving to database

Currently the problem is: It may take long time saving each item to database (Sync DAL), so Parallel.ForEach 1000 items takes forever and the Windows Service application appears slower and slower. Does anyone have good ideas or better approach to gain better performance?

Code snippet:

```
/* Download a list from RESTful API URL.... */
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return DownloadListFromRestAPI(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
task.ContinueWith(i => {
     foreach (var r in i.Result)
      {
          /* For each item, download the item details from RESTful API URL.... */
           var taskSecond = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return DownloadItemDetailFromRestAPI(r.id); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
           taskSecond.ContinueWith(m => {
               /* For each  item detail, get the related business objects, and start Database operation on each object.... */
                List<Item> relatedItems_1000 = s.GetRelatedObjectsIds(m.Result.id);

              /* parallel.ForEach - 1000 or more items  */
                 Parallel.ForEach<Item>(relatedItems_1000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, d => DBLongProcess(d)); /* The DB operation takes long time */
          });
      }
 });
```

Update: (the code for DBLongProcess() and the lock (I added lock because concurrent threads may attempt to modify same object to DB))

```
 private void DBLongProcess(Item item)
 {
    dbDAL.InsertObjectDB(item));
 }

 public class DBDAL
 {
      private readonly object _lock = new object();

      public void InsertObjectDB(Item item)
      {
          lock (_lock)
          {
             if(!item.hasDetail1()){
                 //insert item.detail1...
             }
              if(!item.hasDetail2()){
                //insert item.detail2
             }
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: How does `DBLongProcess` provide thread safety? If done wrong that easily could be the source of your slowness. Can you include the code for that too?

Comment: it is not clear what is the actual problem.
the UI slows down because the Background takes too many resources?

Comment: @NahumLitvin, the problem is the performance is bad. I have no UI and backgroundworker, it's a service application. My question is the line "parallel.foreach 1000 items" seems taking forever.... is there better approach to get better performance?

Comment: isn't your server thread safe? why is the lock?

Comment: @NahumLitvin, please take a look at the source code of "class DBDAL", without lock, conflicts will happen in case two threads insert same item because of this line: if(!item.hasDetail1()).

Comment: why? those are different items.. and if not. quicksort and remove duplications before starting. and than send all the data at once.

Comment: @NahumLitvin, thank you. So your approach is removing the lock in any way. Right? What do you suggest on Parallel.foreach(1000 items)?

Comment: inserting 1000 items 1 by 1 is bad design, why not inserting all at once? This will improve your performance by alot... inserting 1000 items would be 1000 insert statements, dependent on your implementation it could be 1000 roundtrips with new connections...
Anyways, if you have performance issues, first trace your app performance to figure out which part is slowing it down...

Comment: @MichaC, thank you for your response. Actually our business logic inserting an item to database is very complicated. For example, although the application invokes a simple line 'DAL.InsertItem(item)', the DataAccesslayer will validate inputs, convert formats, insert to N tables.....in that case, how to insert all at once? thanks

Comment: @xoyoja as I said, according to your posted code snippets, there is no way I could tell why your application is slow or how to improve it. You have to monitor/trace your code to see where most of the time is spent... I'd recommend to close this question because it cannot be answered

Comment: There is no C# 4.5, did you mean C# 5.0 on .Net 4.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, using `Parallel.ForEach()` won't speed up anything, because the `lock` in `InsertObjectDB()` forces all items to be inserted in series.

What you need to do is to figure a way of making `DBDAL` thread-safe (possibly by using multiple instances of it). If that's not feasible, then you'll have to look for performance improvements elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. If the lock is removed and DBDAL is thread-safe, the Parallel.ForEach (1000+ items) is the best approach of high performance in my case?

Comment: That's hard to say, without knowing the details of your implementation.

Comment: Although I marked this as answer, it doesn't mean the problem is solved. First I will monitor/trace the code to see where most of the time is spent. Then I will try to remove the lock and make the DAL thread safe. I will use more thread-safe caching strategy and commit all the data to DB by batch at once.